# I am a newbie to programming. I am trying to create a wedding tracker and I am working on the GUI. My code is not displaying anything

Tags: java, netbeans

A user should be able to type in their first name and their last name. Use radio buttons to select if they are there for the bride or the groom. Type in their relationship to the bride or groom. Use radio buttons to select if they prefer chicken, pork, or beef for their meal. Then I have JButtons to select at the bottom. One shows the bride's guest list with a time stamp. One shows the groom's list with a time stamp. Another shows the bride's list in alphabetical order, the groom's list in alphabetical order. One has a master list with a time stamp and a master list in alphabetical order. Finally, a meal preference list and exit button.

Isn't this code suppose to print out something?

```
    if (groomstate) {

        groomstate = false;

        Person person = new Person(firstNameTextField.getText(),lastNameTextField.getText(), relationshipTextField.getText(), "bride", "groom");

        PersonNode personNode = new PersonNode(person);

        brideLinkedList.addLast(personNode);

        jTextArea1.append(Person.getfirstName()

            + person.getlastName() + " is with the groom's party and is the "
            + person.getrelationship() + " of the groom.\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, if `groomstate` is false, the whole block will be bypassed. Did you check that?

Comment: Kayaman, O.K. again I'm very new to this. Java programming has not been available. So, my class had to jump over the class and go straight into data structures. I hardly know the basics. However, wouldn't this code help that:  bridestate = false;
        groomstate = true;

Comment: You don't show what's happening before the code, so I can't know if `groomstate` is true or false. Try printing it on the console before the `if` to see what it is (printing on the console is a good way to debug things if you're not familiar with the debugger yet).

Comment: O.K. Thanks a lot. I will try printing it to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for such problems is to debug your code. Put a breakpoint at the line of your if statement, and check what happens there. Here is some tutorial for debugging in Netbeans:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Sorry, that I couldn't post it as a comment, due to not exceeding sufficient rep points ;)

Comment: This should be a comment, and she's using Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

`jTextArea1.append(Person.getfirstName() + person.getlastName() + 
        " is with the groom's party and is the "
        + person.getrelationship() + " of the groom.\n");
    }`

Person.getFirstName() should be person.getfirstName()

Comment: Because of the initialization of person and also the appending of person.getlastName() to the jTextArea1.

Comment: The first name is passed as an argument to the constructor of Person, so it's fair to assume that `getFirstName()` should be an instance method

Comment: Wait, I see what you're saying, my bad, reading this on the train on my phone, missed `Person` and `person` and focused on the `getFirstName` and `getfirstName` :P